# How to fix cloth rig penetration?

Tags: animation, rigging, cloth-simulation

I'm working on cloth rigging.

first I select the cloth mesh and then bones, parented with the empty group. then I selected the rigged mesh and cloth (as active mesh) and applied for weight transfer under weightpaint mode.

I check the rigging and found a lot of glitching, penetration of skin through the cloth. I tried to find help inline but all are scaling up the cloth that is not required in my case so cloth looks inflated.

what should I do?
[image]

Comment: Your trousers is pretty simple so the easiest way if you recreate it from the body's mesh. Go to edit mode of the body, select the area of the mesh what you want to hide with the trousers, duplicate it, increase its thickness with alt+s, then seperate it. Then it will sure has the same weights as the body.

Comment: You can also hide the meh under the clothing with a mask modifier (add vertices to a group then add mask modifier and select the aforecreated group). Mesh is still used for collision but it won't show through.

Comment: yes I agree with Kiskit, in your case use a Mask modifier, or even delete these parts of the legs as they are not useful

Comment: Thank you problem solved! closing the thread. @Kiskit